# For a peer-to-peer app that can resume file transfers, is it sufficient to check filesize/modified date for changes before resuming a file?

Tags: p2p, file-transfer

I'm working on a networked application that has a peer-to-peer file transfer component (think instant messenger), and I'd like to make it able to resume file transfers gracefully.

If there is an ongoing file transfer, and one user drops out, the recipient still knows how much of the file he's successfully received and therefore where to resume the transfer from. However, if the file has changed in the meantime, how can this be detected? With regards to my questions, I'm not focused here on corruption by the network so much as corruption by the source file being altered.

The way I was starting out on this was by having the sender hash the file before sending it, so the recipient has a hash to check the finished file against. However, this only detects corruption at the very end, unless each resume also hashes. This problem could be alleviated by viewing the file in chunks, and hashing each of those. However, the bigger problem with hashing is that it can take a really, really long time, which is just a bad user experience when a user just wants to immediately send something (Ex: Linux ISO on a slow network share is the file to be sent).

I was thinking about changing to simply checking the file size and modified date each time a transfer begins or is resumed. While this is clearly not foolproof, unless I'm missing something (and please correct me if I am), almost every means an end-user would be using to alter files will be well-behaved and at the very least mark the modified date, and even if not, the change in size should catch 99% of cases. Does this seem like an acceptable compromise? Bad idea?

How do the established protocols handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is that it will work in most cases, unless files are modified often.

Instead of hashes, use check sums (CRC32 for example). These are much faster to check whether a file has been modified.

If a connection breaks, you only need to send the computed chunk checksums back to the source which can compute whether the current chunks have been modified in between. Then, it can decide which one to resend and send the missing chunks.

Chunk & checksums are the best trade-off over full files and hashes regarding user experience.